# how can i solve this problem of Post and Get method in laravel 8

Tags: post, routes, get, laravel-8

i want to register some information from the login register , but when i submit the form.
I m getting this error:

```
The GET method is not supported for route admin/register/create. Supported methods: POST
```

here are the codes:

**1- form code:**

```
` <form action=" {{route('admin.register.create')}} " method="POST">
           @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text bg-transparent text-white"><i class="ti-user"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control pl-15 bg-transparent text-white plc-white" placeholder="Full Name">
                </div>
            </div>
</form>     `
```

**2 - web code:**

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
    Route::get("/login",[AdminController::class, "Index"])->name("login_form");
    Route::post("/login/owner",[AdminController::class, "Login"])->name("admin_login");
    Route::get("/dashboard",[AdminController::class, "Dashboard"])->name("admin_dashboard")->middleware("admin");
    Route::get("/logout",[AdminController::class, "AdminLogout"])->name("admin.logout")->middleware("admin");
    Route::get("/register",[AdminController::class, "AdminRegister"])->name("admin.register");
    **Route::post("/register/create"[AdminController::class,"AdminRegisterCreate"])->name("admin.register.create");**

});
```

**3- here is the AdminController:**

```
public function AdminRegisterCreate(Request $request){
       
        $admin = new ModelsAdmin(); // Utilisez le modèle "Admin" du namespace "App\Models\Admin"

    // Remplissez les données de l'administrateur avec les valeurs du formulaire
        $admin->name = $request->input('name');
        $admin->email = $request->input('email');
        $admin->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        $admin->created_at= Carbon::now();
        // Enregistrez l'administrateur dans la base de données
        $admin->save();
        // Alert 
        Auth::guard('admins')->logout();
        return redirect()->route('login_form')->with("error", 'Admin Created Successfully');
}
```

I try to use php artisan route:clear, php artisan route:cache, php artisan optimize, and  php artisan cache:clear
but i did not get nothing